# Shipping information in sales order email

Tags: email-templates

Is it possible to replace the shippingDescription string in the order email templates for a custom phtml file to add a login functionality and a text that has to be translated with a custom language translator class.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class in your own extension adding the function `getShippingDescription` which is called in the email template (see below)

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
   {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
   &nbsp;
</td>
```

The new `getShippingDescription` method would return a block instance from your module that has the modifications you want.

your rewritten Sales Order class `app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Sales/Order.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
   public function getShippingDescription()
   {
      return Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path/to/your/file.phtml')->toHtml();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this a PHP file as I need to add some login/functionality in to this?

I have a custom language translator class that I need to pass text in to.

I guess I would need to override the getShippingDescription() function?

Comment: `order.getShippingDescription()` refers to the `getShippingDescription()` method of the order object, so it already is in it's own PHP class (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order`).  You could rewrite this class and make the necessary changes to the method.

Comment: @JonathanHussey updated my answer and then saw your comment... Great minds think alike? :P

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to `create custom layout` and and assign the `your template file` and with use of block type  `sales/order_email_items` just like oorder item item is render thorh'

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

Step1:just create replicate of this code at email template

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_myshipment" order=$order}}
```

Step2:define handler for this layout at sales.xml

```
<sales_email_order_myshipment>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/your.phtml">
        </block>
      <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_myshipment>
```

On **this phtml file you can get order object** by `$this->getOrder()` now you can  get all details of model

Now do all code here